# Variable and Conditions with Batch Windows

Tags: command-line, batch, filenames

I would like to make a batch.

The goal is simple :

For all files with DSW xtension

If my filename contains VU1 so variable1=2 and variable2=2
If my filename contains VU2 so variable1=20 and variable2=30

End

I try :

```
FOR %%f IN (*VU1*.dsw) DO (
  @echo off set variable1=2
  @echo off set variable2=2 
)
FOR %%f IN (*VU2*.dsw) DO (
  @echo off set variable1=20
  @echo off set variable2=30 
)
```

When I echo my variable, I have got : echo null.

Something is wrong.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `@echo off set variable1=2`  there is the command line `echo off`   and there is the command line `echo abcdefg whatever abcdefg `  you might want @echo off before you start then `echo set variable1=2`  And your code isn't setting any variable because echo just displays. Perhaps you can show what files you have before you run the batch file. And you can show how you check your environment variables too.

Comment: try something like this `@echo off {NEW LINE} FOR %%f IN (*VU1*.dsw) DO ( {NEW LINE}   set variable1=2  {NEW LINE} )`

Comment: Exact my Fault.  ButNow it works only for VU2,

Comment: I suggest you remove the 'echo off' and see if that gives you any clues. And try a batch file that only does VU2 if that fails then just try to fix that, when you have fixed that then you will know where you went wrong and can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is well formulated, so why don't you transform it to *batch commands*?

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem For all files with DSW xtension
FOR %%f IN (*VU*.dsw) DO (

  rem get my filename: no path, no file extension
  set "filename=%%~nf"

  rem initialize variables
  set "variable1=var1" 
  set "variable2=var2"

  rem If my filename contains VU1 so variable1=2 and variable2=2
  If not "!filename:VU1=!"=="!filename!" (
    set "variable1=2" 
    set "variable2=2"
  )
  rem If my filename contains VU2 so variable1=20 and variable2=30
  If not "!filename:VU2=!"=="!filename!" (
    set "variable1=20" 
    set "variable2=30"
  )
  rem display result
  echo %%f "!filename!" !variable1! !variable2!
)
rem end
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```